# Const char *pointer questions?

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers, char

I have some questions related to this simple snippet of code.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   const char *str1;
   str1 = "hello";
   printf("%s \n", str1);
   return 0;
}
```

I want to ask you:

1. Is it safe to make an assignement to a const char pointer like that? Considering that str1 will never change.
2. Is it possibile that at the time of assignment str1 results NULL?

Thank you all!

Comment: At the time of the assignment `str1` is uninitialized. After the assignment it will point to the string literal.

Comment: Yes it's safe. No this is impossible, why should `str1` be NULL after the assignment? _"Considering that str1 will never change"_: but `str1` wille change each time you assign something different to it. The string literal `"Hello"` does not change.

Comment: Many string functions declare their input-only arguments as `const char *`, but of course it's safe to call them with non-const strings; it's just a promise that the contents won't be modified.

Comment: When you see a star (`*`) in front of a variable in C, it means that this variable is pointing to the stuff to the left of this star. So `const char *` variable is a mutable variable pointing to immutable data, while a `char * const` is an immutable variable pointing to mutable data. In this case, you have a pointer to a string literal, which cannot be changed, so you really want it to be `const char *`.

Comment: Could "const char *str1;" be NULL before initialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it safe to make an assignement to a const char pointer like that? Considering that str1 will never change.

Yes. In fact, it's the right thing to do.

The pointer itself is not `const`; the type `const char*` means that the thing it *points to* is `const`.

If your pointer were `const char* const str1` (a const pointer!) then you wouldn't be able to assign to it later. But you'd also get an error for not initialising it in the first place.

> Is it possibile that at the time of assignment str1 results NULL?

No. The literal `"hello"` is never null. No string literal is ever null.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is safe to do the assignment.
2. After the assignment, `str1` will point someplace in the initialized data of the image. Just where is implementation-dependent.

Do not ever attempt to modify the memory at the place pointed to by `str1`, for example by aliasing it with a non-`const` pointer.